# Python 3 if elif else statement isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

After running the code if I type anything other than john or johnny, it still prints out JOHNNY!!! Why is this?

```
user_name = input('What is your name?')

if user_name.lower() == 'john' or 'johnny':
    print ('JOHNNY!!!')
elif user_name.lower() == 'bill' or 'billy':
    print ('BILLY!!!')
else:
    print ('Hello {0}'.format(user_name))
```

Comment: `user_name.lower() in ('john' or 'johnny')` and `elif user_name.lower() in ('bill' or 'billy'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct all your conditions like the following way:

```
if user_name.lower() == 'john' or user_name.lower() =='johnny':
```

A good way to do is

```
if user_name.lower() in {'john' ,'johnny'}:
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much, I REALLY appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

@JacobIRR has a better solution but you can also do what's posted below.

```
user_name = input('What is your name?')

if user_name.lower() == 'john' or user_name.lower() == 'johnny':
    print ('JOHNNY!!!')

elif user_name.lower() == 'bill' or user_name.lower() == 'billy':
    print ('BILLY!!!')

else:
    print ('Hello {0}'.format(user_name))
```